# C: Boolean Test on Matrix Elements

Tags: c, matrix, boolean

To better understand multi-dimensional arrays, I'm writing a tic-tac-toe program, meaning a 3x3 array, initialized at -1 for all elements.

I'm trying to make the "win" condition become true when all elements of a row/column/diagonal are equal (and not empty, thus different from -1).

But I keep winning... When I should not, and the games continues when it should be over. How can I fix it?

This is (part of) my code:

```
#define GRID_SIZE 3
#define EMPTY -1
#define PLAYER0 0
#define PLAYER1 1

printf("Player %d turn: Insert the tile coordinates\n", player);
scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

/* Update tile */

if (player == PLAYER0)
    grid[x][y] = PLAYER0;
else
    grid[x][y] = PLAYER1;

/*  Winning diagonals? */

i = 0;
d1 = ((grid[i][i] == grid[i+1][i+1] == grid[i+2][i+2]) && (grid[i][i] != EMPTY));
d2 = ((grid[i][GRID_SIZE-i-1] == grid[i+1][GRID_SIZE-i] == grid[i+2][GRID_SIZE-i+1])     && (grid[i][GRID_SIZE-i-1] != EMPTY));

if ((d1) || (d2)) {
        printf("Player %d wins!\n", player);
        victory_or_draw = 1;
}

/*  Winning rows or column? */

for (j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE; ++j) {
    row = ((grid[i][j] == grid[i+1][j] == grid[i+2][j]) && (grid[i][j] != EMPTY));
    column = ((grid[j][i] == grid[j][i+1] == grid[j][i+2]) && (grid[j][i] != EMPTY)); 
    if ((row) || (column)) {
        printf("Player %d wins!\n", player);
        victory_or_draw = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comparison operators are not transitive in C, you should use the Boolean "and" operator `&&` to combine different tests.

Also, when posting code here cook it down to a minimal example. Your problem has nothing to do with the fact that this is done for elements of a matrix.

Comment: Thank you! At the beginning I had that doubt, but I was fooled by the compiler not protesting... I should have checked anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot compare like this

```
(grid[i][i] == grid[i+1][i+1] == grid[i+2][i+2])
```

Use like

```
(grid[i][i] == grid[i+1][i+1] && grid[i][i] == grid[i+2][i+2])
```

Change your d1 and d2 to

```
d1 = ((grid[i][i] == grid[i+1][i+1] && grid[i][i] == grid[i+2][i+2]) && (grid[i][i] != EMPTY));
d2 = ((grid[i][GRID_SIZE-i-1] == grid[i+1][GRID_SIZE-i] && grid[i][GRID_SIZE-i-1] == grid[i+2][GRID_SIZE-i+1]) && (grid[i][GRID_SIZE-i-1] != EMPTY));
```

Change same thing in your `for` loop also.